# Azure Microservice : Unable to acquire ssl credentials: CertificateNotFound

Tags: security, service, cloud, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I am stuck with this error message.

> Unable to acquire ssl credentials: CertificateNotFound

I have an Azure Micro-service S1 trying to connect to another Micro-Service S2 using Remote Procedure Calls. Without SSL the Call works fine but when I added code to communicate to each other using SSL Certificate then I get the above error message. I have followed this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-secure-communication.

I have installed a certificate on my Local Machine and I can see that in MMC explorer.

Here is view of my SSL Certificate:

[image: view]

Comment: Did you put the correct Thumbprint in your code?

Comment: Yes I have correct Thumb Print specified

Comment: <Section Name="test">
    <Parameter Name="MaxMessageSize" Value="10000000" />
    <Parameter Name="SecurityCredentialsType" Value="X509" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateFindType" Value="FindByThumbprint" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateFindValue" Value="0ea49f0d1f839e96c3665beb4ff6d0033c33"/>
    <Parameter Name="CertificateStoreLocation" Value="LocalMachine" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateStoreName" Value="My" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateProtectionLevel" Value="EncryptAndSign" />
    <Parameter Name="CertificateRemoteCommonNames" Value="Test-Cert" />
  </Section>

Comment: Section name should always end with "TransportSettings"

Comment: Yes it is , I have just omitted that here because of stackoverflow characters limit.

Comment: I thought I had it :)  Did you try using code to get the cert?

Comment: Yes I have tried but No Luck :(. The error message says CertificateNotFound and its looking into the directory "LocalMachine\My" which effectively maps to "LocalMachine\Personal"

Comment: can you try adding an ACL for NETWORK SERVICE explicitly to allow it access to the private key? Is the certificate's intended use correct?

Comment: maybe you're running into this issue: When copying a certificate thumbprint from the certificate store snap-in on Windows, an invisible character is placed at the beginning of the thumbprint string. This invisible character can cause an error when trying to locate a certificate by thumbprint, so be sure to delete this extra character.

Comment: I manually entered the ThumbPrint now. Looks like previously it was not finding Certificate because of that invalid character. which is a step forward. But now I get a different error

Comment: {
  "Timestamp": "2017-03-14T15:56:01.4661748+00:00",
  "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",
  "Id": 4096,
  "Message": "Unable to acquire ssl credentials: 0x8009030e ",
  "ProcessId": 11136,
  "Level": "Error",
  "Keywords": "0x8000000000000001",
  "EventName": "Transport",
  "Payload": {
    "id": "",
    "type": "Security",
    "text": "Unable to acquire ssl credentials: 0x8009030e"
  }
}

Comment: Previously it was "Unable to acquire ssl credentials: CERTIFICATENOTFOUND" but now its 0x8009030. I have used a test certificate from from internet that somebody posted for test. Do you think it has to do anything with the type of the certificate?

Comment: Yes, try using a self signed cert for test purposes using ServiceFabricRPHelpers.psm1.

Comment: Did you remember to include the private key woth your certificate when you exported it?